# Does transform scale effect on distances?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, scale, getboundingclientrect

I'm trying to make a backgammon game with Javascript and CSS and tried to make all elements size with **PX** and get moving distance of pieces by this way:

```
let start = FromElement.getBoundingClientRect().x;   //imagine start = 50

let end = ToElement.getBoundingClientRect().x;       //imagine end = 60

piece.style.transform = "translateX(" + (end - start) + ")";    //60 - 50 = 10
```

*Please don't attend to **vertical** movement*

Now when I transform my root element (Board Element) to fit the board to the page, I see that addition to scaling the start and end ( for example with 1.5x scaling, start: 75 & end: 90), the distance will change during to start and end changing (become 90 - 75 : 15) and change another time by scaling (15 * 1.5: 22.5) so I saw a bad translation.

*every size is by **PX** but I can't understand where is problem!?!?!?  :(*

> I think this will good to say that I understand that by saw distance will decrease when I set page width smaller than the main size!!!

This is a part of understanding what is my problem! ( *I undo my move after first move*)
[image]

Comment: Have you the same problem for other transformation methods? (scale, etc ...) I mean if it's only about the translation, just use absolute positioning and other stuffs

Comment: if the element are child of the scaled element then you don't need to change anything to your translations

Comment: @Mohsen all positions are by absolute positioning and their move are good before scaling but after that i see some additional values

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, But what happens here :(((

Comment: we cannot know without a full working code